# Calculate average in excel excluding cell contains date or zero or text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

[image]

In B6 I want to calculate average for range c6:h6 skipping cells which has date, zero or non text values.

Result should be - 400

I tried using averageif with filter ex: =AVERAGE(FILTER(C6:H6,ISNUMBER(C6:H6))) but not getting correct result

Thank you

Comment: What is the format of cells with dates? If they are formatted as date, it is normal to not get the correct average as Excel stores dates as numbers. Changes their formats if they are formatted as dates. [See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaYqF.png).

Comment: I am using google sheet, if I change format as text it may work, but problem is I wont get date selector popup

Comment: To make things easier, change the layout of your data. Dates should be in one column (let say C) and their values in also one column (let say D). It will allow you to get the average easily with a formula such as =AVERAGE(D1:D3).

Comment: Thanks that would have been easier, but I don't have one category I have many and at the end I am totalling them. Its like a expense sheet with big data so cant make changes into layout

Comment: Is there a way I can check if column has header then only it should be consider

Comment: You can use AVERAGEIF function: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/averageif.php

Answer (score 0):

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C5:H5,"Amount",C6:H6, ">0", C6:H6)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your precise case, use the following, edited for your exact cell range:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(C1:H1,1,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(C1:H1)/2,2,2)))
```

Edit the input range `C1:J1` to match your exact input range. The second parameter of `SEQUENCE()` can be found as shown given that you have pairs of values.

`AVERAGE()` seems to ignore zero values on its own. NOT my memory for it from using it maybe ten years ago, but things change, and my memory might be wrong anyway. So it will ignore zero entries (does in my testing), both when summing items and when deciding what value to divide by.

**Update on the above:  it ignores BLANKS and text, but not actual zeros.** So if there could be zeros that should not be part of the average (it seems like they should not be entered at all, if so, but real life often does not match logical life...), either because they should not have been entered, but were, or because even though they are legitimate values, one simply does not want to use them, then there is no good reason to go down this path to an even more complicated formula when `Mobus`'s formula will handle them nicely. However, if the values come from calculations and the zeros occur simply as the default output of said formulas, it will happily ignore `""` entries so the formulas in the cells could have a nice `IF()` that results in `""` instead of `0`. Still... moving from similar complexity to more complex, so `Mobus`'s would still be preferred.

While that's nice (I expected the tough part to be eliminating the zero entries, though it seemed something like `FILTER(TRANSPOSE())` would have done the trick), it does mean that when there are NO entries, you will be dividing by zero and so getting an error you might want to plan for.

What makes this work for the exact kind of case you present is the regularity of your data structure. It allows knowledge to separate out those date entries and not include them in the array passed to `AVERAGE()`. If your data is actually messy, then this won't work, not without some massaging of it or the data anyway.

Takeaway either way? Excel often does not need something overly complex as knowledge about the data can often allow a huge simplification of what you actually need Excel to do for you. Like applying simple algebra to a problem, getting a simple end result, and doing that simple end result in your Excel formula, not the original, hard to even state statement of the problem.

*(This is where people often get preachy about making the data structure "right" right from the beginning, **but not everyone has that luxury** and a formula like this has to be the bridge that pulls things together. That said, if you have the ability to change your data structure, that might lead to an easier to understand and to maintain spreadsheet.)*

Hmm... you've tagged with the 2007 and 2010 version tags I see. That makes it a wee bit different as you need to generate the sequence `SEQUENCE()` is used for in a different way. This will do that:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(C1:J1,1,  ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&(COLUMNS(C1:H1)+2)/2))*2)  )
```

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2007 and later:
 `=AVERAGEIF($5:$5,"Amount",6:6)`

In Excel versions earlier than 2007, you can try this ***array*** formula:

```
B2: =AVERAGE(IF($5:$5="Amount",6:6,"x"))
```

In the earlier versions of Excel, to enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

***Note***

- The `AVERAGE` function will ignore text

[image]